# Data.frame row calculation

Tags: r

I want to calculate rows in my `data.frame` with a simple function (for e.g. `[sqrt(column1 * column 2)]`). This is my function. I have 17 rows in which I want to calculate the function to create a new column called `d`.

How to make it? With combine? With `t(x)` transfering the `data.frame` into a matrix? Or with which function? I want it to still have a `data.frame` (as a table).

Comment: Have you tried something like `sqrt(column1 * column 2)`? You probably should take a look at an intro. Here is the official intro manual : https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html . It's a bit dry, but Appendix A would be worth going through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options to choose from:

**Base R**

```
df$d <- sqrt(df$column1^2 +df$column2^2)
#or
transform(df, d=sqrt(column1^2+column2^2))
```

**Tidyverse**

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- df %>%
  mutate( d = sqrt(column1^2+column2^2))

head(df)
```

All these methods preserve your data as a data frame

Comment: Why? What tidyverse or `mutate` adds to your answer that couldn't be done without it?

Comment: Personally I find it's syntax easier to understand, though the base R solution of `iris$d <- sqrt(iris$Petal.Length^2+iris$Petal.Width^2)` would be equal in this case.

Comment: Base R has many additional solutions which you could find easy to understand, such as `with` or `transform`, e.g., `transform(iris, NewColumn = sqrt(Petal.Length^2 + Petal.Width^2))`. Is that easy enough for you?

Comment: I'm a big fan of `dplyr` but for what it's worth, here's my preferred base R solution: `df$c <- sqrt(df$column1 * df$column2)`

Comment: I'll be honest, I didn't know about the `transform` function. I've always used `dplyr` for data manipulation.

Comment: Thank you for answerung Michael Bird. First my R shows me Errors, cause df is not found and with my function i tried it, but many errors come along. What did you mean with df? Im really a newbie in R but had lessons a few months ago.

Comment: Also i get the error: Object of type 'Closure' is not indexable - so what to do? I dont know what 'Closure' in this context means...

Comment: Alsi i tried the solution from David Arenburg: i got the error: Petal.Length (in my case dmin_mu) not found. What i have to set as petal.length?

Comment: When i say `df` I'm using it as a place holder for the name of a generic `data.frame`, as you have for column names `column1` and `column2` You will need to adapt these solutions to take your own data.